# Rangequery No Longer Works in Lucene 2.9.4.1

Tags: c#, lucene.net

After upgrading from Lucene.Net 2.3.1.3 to 2.9.4.1, a RangeQuery no longer works.  I tried NumericRangeQuery and TermRangeQuery with no luck. The RangeQuery searches for Long values in a range (ex - [4000 TO 5000] should find 4500).

Here is the code:

```
    private static Query BuildNumericRangeQuery(NumericRangeSearchParam.NumericRangeField range)
    {
        var startTerm = new Term(range.FieldName, NumberTools.LongToString(range.Start));
        var endTerm = new Term(range.FieldName, NumberTools.LongToString(range.End));
        return new RangeQuery(startTerm, endTerm, true);
    }
```

Anyone else run into the same issue?  Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: RangeQuery is deprecated; rewrite your query to use TermRangeQuery or NumericRangeQuery instead. http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/RangeQuery.html

Comment: I tried both NumericRangeQuery and TermRangeQuery with no results.  I did find that the data is being padded to 10 characters with the following: 
    
    var transformation = (int) Math.Floor(rating*1000);
                        var result = ToLexographical(transformation, 10);

...which results in 0000004500 as an example.

Comment: Yes, and the same padding is applied during indexing too, right?

Comment: Yes, that ToLexigraphical call was for the Index crawler.  That was the issue.  I changed it to ToLexographical(transformation, 4) which results in a 4 character string (ex - 4500).  That worked!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to the Index Crawler padding the data to 10 characters with the following:

```
var transformation = (int) Math.Floor(rating*1000);
var result = ToLexographical(transformation, 10); //which results in 0000004500 as an example.
```

I changed it to ToLexographical(transformation, 4) which results in a 4 character string (ex - 4500). Not sure how this worked before because [4000 TO 5000] shouldn't technically find 0000004500 with Lexographic ordering.